# javascript form validation button disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to see if all of the form inputs are filled and meet my specifications. On every 'keyup' event that occurs between the input fields, a function 'checker' is called to validate the inputs. If something is not right, the submit button should be disabled. For some reason, the button never gets disabled so I assume it's a logic error.

```
$('.confirm,.password,.username,.email').on('keyup', function(){
    if(!checker){
        $('.submit').prop('disabled', true);    
    }else{
        $('.submit').prop('disabled', false);   
    }
});


function checker(){
    if(!($('.username').length >= 2 && $('.username').length <= 12) || !( 
        isValidEmailAddress($('.email').val())) || !($('.password').length 
        >= 8 && $('.password').length <= 20 ) || !($('.confirm').length 
        >= 8 && $('.confirm').length <= 20) || !($('.password').val() === 
        $('.confirm').val()))
        {
            return False;
        }else{
            return True;
        }   
}
```

The way I have it set up is that if one of the paired conditions is true ($('.username').length >= 2 && $('.username').length <= 12), then it will be turned false and not trigger the if statement to return false. If something is wrong, the if statement should return true.

Comment: It looks like your call to checker is incorrect in your if statement. Try this if(!checker())

Comment: You are checking against a variable, not the function. Change it to `if (!checker())`.

Comment: `$('.username').length <= 12` you have up to 12 username fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two small things:

- You need to actually invoke `checker()`. Right now you are simply checking if `checker` exists at all in your expression and not resolving against its return value.
- Change `True/False` to `true/false`. `True/False` isn't defined in JavaScript.

> > True
> >     ReferenceError: True is not defined

```js
$('.confirm,.password,.username,.email').on('keyup', function(){
    if(!checker()){
        $('.submit').prop('disabled', true);    
    }else{
        $('.submit').prop('disabled', false);   
    }
});


function checker(){
    if(!($('.username').length >= 2 && $('.username').length <= 12) || !( 
        isValidEmailAddress($('.email').val())) || !($('.password').length 
        >= 8 && $('.password').length <= 20 ) || !($('.confirm').length 
        >= 8 && $('.confirm').length <= 20) || !($('.password').val() === 
        $('.confirm').val()))
        {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="password"></input>
<input class="username"></input>
<input class="email"></input>
<button class="submit">submit<button>
```

Also, that isn't how you check for length of an input in jQuery. You have to check `$('.password')[0].val().length`.

You should also take a look at this https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 0):

`if(!checker)` says "If the box labeled `checker` is a falsey value, run this block"

You are wanting to say "If the result of calling the box labeled `checker` is falsey, run this block."

To do that, we need to invoke `checker`:

`if(!checker())`

Answer (score 0):

Don't validate the form with javascript. Use the constraint validation instead. Also don't disable the submit button. Clicking it in a state when the form is invalid gives feedback to what is wrong with the form, you can not get it if the button is disabled.

```html
<form>
  <input type="password" required minlength="8" maxlength="20" placeholder="password"><br>
  <!-- comfirm -->
  <input type="password" required minlength="8" maxlength="20" placeholder="repeat password"><br>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
  <input type="text" name="username" minlength="2" maxlength="12" placeholder="username"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Also why would you want to set a maxlength on the password? that is just dumb. Think it takes up too much in the database? you should always hash it and then it will be a fixed length always.

Comment: I've never encountered constraint validation but that is definitely helpful. I also agree about the password maxlength - I do not know why I have that after thinking about it.

Comment: still have to validate the comfirm with js doe... but do that on change event or `form.onsubmit`, never on `button.onclick`